# Calling a block/closure from the same scope

Tags: ios, swift, timer, closures

I am creating an app that has the screen switch rapidly between black and white. For this I am using a `Timer`,

My problem boils down to not being able to call a function from the same scope (`changeBackgroundColor`) in timer's declaration.

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: changeBackgroundColor) 
//Error: 'Cannot convert value of type '(ViewController) -> (Timer) -> Void' to expected argument type '(Timer) -> Void'

func changeBackgroundColor(timer: Timer) -> Void {
    //change the color of the screen (not the issue here)
}
```

I thought I had understood closures but there seems to be a problem with the scopes here.

Comment: A class's propperties are given their initial values before there is a `self` to reference. You just need to initialize it at a different time when `self` is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of using the "block" version of a timer is to avoid having to create a separate function.

You should write it as follows:

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
    // change the color of the screen
}
```

Comment: But starting the Timer inside my touchesBegan() makes it impossible to invalidate it from touchesEnded.

Comment: Make `timer` a property instead of a local variable.

Comment: But wouldn't that immediately start it, when the ViewController loads?

Comment: No. You still create the timer where you want. You are simply changing the scope of the variable so you can access it from other methods.